# A Material that has Colourful, Swirly Turbulence

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, materials

How could I make a colour turbulence material like, so from a pic? I would need help with this thing.

[image: te]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not exact but maybe can get you in the right direction.

I just used a mixRGB node for all the different colors I needed. Then I just seperated the colors with a noise texture. The trick is to change to distortion on the node to get those swirls.

Use the ColorRamps to control how sharp you want the edges of the swirls to be.

It will just take some playing around with all the settings I circled to get that specific look.

[image]
[image]